# Cordova and PhoneGap initialization failed on Sencha Command

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cordova, sencha-touch

I had installed PhoneGap through NodeJS CLI on my Ubuntu 13.10 and started native build process. However, during the initialization, this was the executed command and the respective output.

```
    $ sencha phonegap init com.foo.barapp BarApp
    Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67
    [INF] 
    [INF] sencha-phonegap-init:
    [INF] 
    [INF] init-phonegap:
    [INF]      [echo] Adding PhoneGap to Application
    [INF]      [echo] Adding PhoneGap template files
    [INF]      [echo] Adding Native properties
    [INF] [x-property-file] Updating property file: /tmp/BarApp/.sencha/app/native.properties
    [INF] [x-property-file] Updating property file: /tmp/BarApp/.sencha/app/build.properties
    [INF]      [echo] Patching build.xml for PhoneGap Support
    [INF]      [echo] Building PhoneGap App
    [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
    /opt/sencha/cmd/4.0.2.67/extensions/cmd-phonegap-packager/cmd-phonegap-packager.plugin.xml:131: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    jar:file:/opt/sencha/cmd/4.0.2.67/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608: shellscript returned: 1
```

This same issued happened to Cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was redefine the env value set in phonegap.js:

```
    $ git diff phonegap.js

    $ diff --git a/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js b/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
    index b6e469b..e1eb83f 100755
    --- a/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
    +++ b/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
    @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
    -#!/usr/bin/env node
    +#!/usr/bin/env nodejs

    /*!
     * Module dependencies.eplace the interpreted value set at phonegap.js file.
```

The same can be done to Cordova script.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me with Cordova on Ubuntu 13.10.
To fix cordova (on global installment) just edit following file: **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova**

```
-#!/usr/bin/env node
+#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```