# Cordova and PhoneGap not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, extjs, cordova

I installed Cordova and PhoneGap with npm:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

however, both return the same error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Both files are using node instead of nodejs as interpreted. The fix can be found at post [Sencha PhoneGap Init failed on Ubuntu 13.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272569/sencha-phonegap-init-failed-on-ubuntu-13-10)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

it's not finding node or node lib on your path

There different solutions posted here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911

A few:
PATH:

appending /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin');
```

Symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Installing node legacy:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: The symlink solution works fine in case you used a package manager to install it

Answer (score 25):

The next command helps:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a shortcut in `/usr/local` (not `/usr/bin`):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

According to [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/usr-fs.html), *distributions may not install anything in there. It is reserved solely for the use of the local administrator.*

*This way he/she can be absolutely certain that no updates or upgrades to his distribution will overwrite any extra software he has installed locally.*

If you are a full-stack developer requiring later features, I recommend installing the latest [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) according [Ask Ubuntu instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656).

Remember that [Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) provides [Node.JS v0.10.25 (stable)](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.25/).

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo apt-get install npm
```